# Wordpress changing script source from https to http

Tags: php, wordpress

In my header, I am using wp_enqueue_script to load some external files. The path begins https, but when I view the source in the browser, it changes to http.

Here is what I have:

```
wp_enqueue_script('handle', 'https://secure.example.com/path/file.aspx',array(), true);
```

But in the head, when I view source in the browser, I get this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://secure.example.com/path/file.aspx?ver=1'></script>
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Are you sure that it's WordPress? Have you tried visiting the link?

Comment: @isherwood yes I am sure. I am working in the Wordpress files, specifically the header.php file

Comment: this seems weird.  Are you 100% sure that you're editting the right code?  Try changing the script url to something *completely* different and see if that updates.  If its still changing your protocol to http://, maybe its a bug?  Are you using the latest WP?

Comment: also, note that there is a WP specific stackexchange site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ZachL Thanks. Yes, I was editing the right code. My browser was just having issues with caching. Cleared the cache and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... Have you tried clearing your cache?